# Aliases: difference between .bash_rc, .bash_aliases and /usr/local/bin

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

Playing around with Terminal, I noticed that there are many ways to create **permanent** aliases.

I'm a Linux newbie, and from what I know, doing:

1. `sudo ln -s /path/to/executable /usr/local/bin/desired_alias`
2. adding `desired_alias = '/path/to/executable'` to `~/.bashrc`
3. uncommenting those lines in `~/.bashrc`:

   ```bsh
   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
       . ~/.bash_aliases
   fi
   ```

   and putting `desired_alias = '/path/to/executable'` into the `~/.bash_aliases`

all have the same effect.

What is the difference between the first and second methods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the first method you are not creating an alias, you are creating a symlink. Symlinks are short for symbolic links:

> Symbolic  links  are files that act as
>   pointers to other files. [...] A 
>   symbolic link is a special type of
>   file whose contents are a string that
>   is the pathname another file, the file
>   to which the link refers.  In other
>   words, a symbolic link is a pointer to
>   another name, and not to an underlying
>   object.

Read more about symlinks [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/symlink.7.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

Only with the second method you are, in fact, creating an alias.

> Aliases  allow  a  string  to be
>   substituted for a word when it is used
>   as the first word of a simple command.
>   The shell maintains a list of aliases
>   that may be set and unset with the
>   alias and unalias builtin commands
>   (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS  below).
>   The  first  word of each simple
>   command, if unquoted, is checked to
>   see if it has an alias. If so, that
>   word is replaced by the text of the
>   alias.

You can define an alias anywhere where you can type a command and have the shell (*bash* in this case) interpret it, however in order for the alias to be available in other shells it needs to be defined in a file that's interpreted by the shell on startup (shell startup, not computer startup).

For bash these are `/etc/bash.bashrc` (system wide) and `~/.bashrc`. These files are interpreted when the shell starts in interactive mode (like when using `Terminal`). I'm not going to mention the profile files because they serve a different purpose.

So, you want to add your aliases to `~/.bashrc` to have them available in every interactive shell.

The `.bash_aliases` method accomplishes *exactly* the same thing as putting the aliases in `~/.bashrc` but has the added benefit of being easier to be parsed and manipulated by programs.

The `. ~/.bash_aliases` means source (load) `_~/.bash_aliases_` in the context of the currently running shell.

Comment: @lilo you beat me to the tutorial! +1

Comment: @gc I'm hitting the sack so go wild :)

Comment: @lilo hahahha  :)

Comment: thanks, but why the symbolic link in /usr/local/bin is working as well?

Comment: You may think it's working the same, but it's not. Please read the materials on symlinks that I referred in my answer. Symlink and aliases serve different purposes and were created with different purposes in mind. To give you an example why symlinks are not working like aliases try this -- define an alias like: alias px="ps axu". Now try to accomplish the same with symlinks.

Comment: @Li Lo: i have understood the difference between synlink and /usr/local/bin, but my question (that's maybe a little bit off-topic with the general question) is: what is exaclty /usr/local/bin used for?

Comment: @daniel: /usr/local/bin: Binaries for programs local to the site (from "man hier"). For example if you would compile and install a program from sources it would go to /usr/local/bin.