# How to call just a function from text script?

Tags: command-line

I have a text file with a lot of functions in it. for example:

```bsh
# fisrt function
# runs update and upgrade
    function upug() {
        sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
    }

# second function
# find out the processes running that use the most memory
    function memusage() {
        ps aux | sort -nrk 4 | head
    }
# third function
# install package
    function ipkg() {
        sudo apt-get install
    }
[...]
```

Now I want to able use these functions as the similar something as follows in terminal:

- with running `upug` in terminal calls `function upug()`

  ```
  user@test-pc:~$ upug
  ```
- with running `memusage` in terminal calls `function memusage()`

  ```
  user@test-pc:~$ memusage
  ```
- with unning `ipkg package_Name` calls `function ipkg()`

  ```
  user@test-pc:~$ ipkg package_Name
  ```

I created an alias for each of these commands with function names. now question is how can I call these function with alias name of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd put both the functions and the aliases into my `~/.bash_aliases` (See [Aliases: difference between .bash_rc, .bash_aliases and /usr/local/bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2528/aliases-difference-between-bash-rc-bash-aliases-and-usr-local-bin)).

Since you already have the aliases defined in your current session, you could just source the text file to later call the alias commands:

```
user@test-pc:~$ . <PATH_TO_YOUR_TEXT_COMMANDS>/my_commands.txt
user@test-pc:~$ upug
```

Alternatively you can load the file from your `~/.bashrc` as follow:

```
if [ -f <PATH_TO_YOUR_TEXT_COMMANDS>/my_commands.txt ]; then
    . <PATH_TO_YOUR_TEXT_COMMANDS>/my_commands.txt
fi
```

Comment: Only if you keep them in a separate file, but they will be automatically loaded if put in `~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: If you want to keep them in a separate file, you can also load it from your `.bashrc` file, applying the same mechanism used to load the `~/.bash_aliases`. See the question I linked in my answer for the related code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code I was referring to