# Call functions from C program in terminal

Tags: command-line

This is driving me absolutely crazy because it's such a simple thing to do but I can't seem to get it.

Let's say I have a program called test.c whose content is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int bool_or(int x, int y) {
        int result = x|y;
        //return result;
        printf("%d\n", result);
}

int bool_xor(int x, int y) {
    int result= x^y;
        //return result;
        printf("%d\n", result);
}
}
```

Now let's say I want to make a function call to one of those functions from the terminal. How do I do that? I compiled the program and I can manually comment out the function definitions and input specific values in the editor and get something to display, but what if I want to simply just write something like bool_xor(3, 5) on the command line like I would if I were running a language like Python.

Basically what I'm asking is how do I make a function call.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to define multiple function inside `main(){...}` function??

Comment: Similar to this Q/A [How to call just a function from text script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/518335/283843)

Comment: Should I not be able to? How else could I go about running a function or having multiple functions in a single text file?

Also I checked the Q/A and I tried it out but it didn't work because bool_or and bool_xor aren't already defined functions.

Comment: ask this on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you have to read up on C syntax. There were two major issues:

- Defining functions inside `main` is not possible in *standard* C and even in the GCC extension, it certainly doesn't work how you think it does.
- Calling a function doesn't happen by magic, you must tell what to use as parameters and how to rework them to a suitable form.

I have re-worked your code to a working state (in a file called `bool_xor.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bool_xor(int x, int y) {
    int result= x^y;
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc<3) {
        printf("Too few args.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return bool_xor( atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]) );
}
```

And now compile and a couple of simple tests:

```
$ gcc -Wall --pedantic -o bool_xor bool_xor.c 

$ ./bool_xor 1 2
3

$ ./bool_xor 7 5
2
```

To create a separate `or` function, you will either need to reengineer the `main()` to decide which function it's calling or just have another `bool_or.c` file and generate a separate binary that does that single job (like this one does).

Here's an example of a combined `compare.c` that takes an `xor` or `or` argument before the values to determine which internal function to execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int bool_or(int x, int y) {
    printf("%d\n", x|y);
    return 0;
}

int bool_xor(int x, int y) {
    printf("%d\n", x^y);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc!=4) {
        printf("Needs 3 parameters. Expects:\n\t%s xor|or value value\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* TODO check that arguments are valid */

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "xor") == 0)
        return bool_xor( atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]) );
    return bool_or( atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]) );
}
```

Comment: I believe GCC has extensions for nested functions, but yes, this is not portable C.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html - right! I learnt something new today. ;-)

Comment: There's an obvious exception to the "Calling a function doesn't happen by magic" point in that the `main` function is called implicitly.

Comment: I like the edits, somehow it proves that even if you think you know the answer - you still might be wrong, at least partly.

Comment: @Hannu I would like how to call a special function from the bash or something like this, and this is not really the answer to this.

Comment: @ LittleByBlue: If the above is not what you were looking for, then sadly the wording in your question doesn't tell what you intended - making it hard to answer :-] .

Comment: @LittleByBlue C is not an interpreted language to be used so, I'm afraid.